# page getting redirected to wrong page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement

I have a simple login form that allows a user to login, although the form is working fine, but there is one condition where i wish to redirect it to someother page, instead of regular index page.

piece of code where i am facing issue is

```
if($spid=="")
    {
        header('Location:index.php');
    }
else
    {
        header('Location:new.php?id=$spid');
    }
```

the issue is even if the $spid has a value it is getting redirected to index.php page. can anyone please tell why this is happening

the whole code from which the above code has been extracted is

```
<?php
$spid=$_GET['spid'];
$emailErr = $pswrdErr = $loginErr = "";
$email = $password = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
                $emailErr = "Email is required";
            } 
        else {
                $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
                if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                        $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
                    }
            }

        if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
                $pswrdErr = "password is required";
            }   
        else {
                $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
            }   

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usertable where email='".$email."' and password='".$password."' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
                        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

                        if($spid=="")
                            {
                                header('Location:index.php');
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                header('Location:new.php?id=$spid');
                            }

                    }
            }
        else {
                $loginErr = "Invalid Credentials";
            } 
    } 

function test_input($data) {
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST" role="form">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried echoing the value of $spid to see what is actually being stored in it?

Comment: @James yes i did that, and it has the value

Comment: Have you tried changing `if($spid=="")` to `if(empty($spid))` instead and see if it works?

Comment: Try using `if (empty($spid)) {
    header('Location:index.php');
}` instead and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: `'Location:new.php?id=$spid'`, shouldn't that be `"Location:new.php?id=$spid"`?

Comment: @Mark doesn't matter, if it did, the redirect to index.php wouldn't have worked either.

Comment: @James its not working with if (empty($spid)) also

Comment: @Epodax it's not about whether or not the redirect is happening, but what is passed in the querystring. Using single quotes will pass $spid as is, while using double quotes would insert the value of $spid. I haven't read the 2nd codeblock, only noticed what might be an error in the first.

Comment: When you echo the value, what does it spit out?

Comment: @James it gives single numeric value such as 2 or 6 or 9...etc

Comment: @Mark While that is true, it still does not matter to the issue at the hand, even if the value wasn't echoed correctly he would end up with `new.php?id=` instead, and not `index.php`

Comment: I've tried this at my end and there is no reason it shouldn't work. when you echo the value to the page, where are you placing the echo statement? If you take out the redirects and replace them with `echo $spid;` what explicitly gets displayed on the page?

Comment: @James if i use this if else condition before $emailErr = $pswrdErr = $loginErr = ""; and instead of header just echo simple text i get proper result but if i use it with header it gives me wrong result

Comment: So when you use `echo $spid;` instead of `header('Location:index.php');` what do you get on the page?

Comment: @James i get its original value (which is numeric)

Comment: @Epodax First of all, it will redirect to `new.php?id=$spid` (not simply `new.php?id=`). Also, we don't have enough information to judge whether or not it matters. `new.php` might redirect to index if `id` is not an INT.

Answer (score 1):

As you said you are getting value in `$spid=$_GET['spid'];` So instead of following above mentioned method take your `$spid` as hidden i/p text inside form and then pass it in your code as

`$finalspid=$_POST["spid"]`

and then put your if else condition according to `$finalspid`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(!isset($spid) && $spid==''){
   header('Location:index.php');
} else {
   header("Location:new.php?id=".$spid);
}
```

Comment: i tried using ur code, but now it is redirecting to new.php everytime even when $spid is blank

Comment: Are you passing 'spid' with url?

Comment: yes and instead of picking value of spid the url that i get at nego.php page is www.example.com/new.php?id=$spid

Comment: have you try to print $spid value by var_dump($spid);

Comment: i tried your query it didn't work, however i also tried your var_dump($spid); (i didnt do it earlier) inside the while loop i am getting value of $spid as NULL but if i print it at the starting then i get its value properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86768/discussion-between-chintan7027-and-st001).

Comment: Good. You got a solution but try to find solution with GET method. It easy to do this with POST

Comment: `if $spid is not set AND $spid equals a string` ...what?